# Sorting User Input Bash

Tags: bash

Suppose that I have a bash program that takes in three integer arguments:

```
./test  9 8 7
```

I want to be able to sort these values so that the largest value is assigned to a variable c. How can I do this?

Comment: You just want max value or want to sort the given numbers?

Comment: `echo "9 8 7" | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -nr | head -n1`

Comment: I would like the max value

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where did you get stuck? Reading the input or doing the sorting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to get the max value from given list of numbers as arguments to your script:

```
max=0                      # initialize max to 0

for i; do                  # short cut to iterate over "$@"
    ((i > max)) && max=$i  # reset max to current value if val > max
done

echo "max=$max"
```

Comment: @RedShift: Did this work for you?